# Network connection failed in Red 5 server

Tags: windows, php, java, html, red5

I am new to red5 server.

When I try to run Red5 by creating a project in Eclipse using the Red5 plugin it runs with an error:

> [INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Scope default1 not found on localhost

When I try to run the client, it shows `unsuccessful connection`.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697254/red5-open-source-chat-scope-rtmpclient-not-found-on-localhost)?

It has four answers with possible solutions or workarounds.  To get anything more specific, you'll probably need to provide more details about the failure and what you have or haven't tried.  Otherwise any answer is going to be a shot in the dark.